# How to create a database in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm very new to DynamoDB. While reading the documentation, I've seen the [following sentence](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html):

> In Amazon DynamoDB, a database is a collection of tables. A table is a collection of items and each item is a collection of attributes.

Nevertheless, [all I can found](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/APISummary.html) are methods to play with tables, items and attributes, and nothing is said about how to create a database.

So my questions is: is it possible to create databases within my user account, or are all the tables created within a "common shared default" database (i.e. my user account is the unique "database")?

It would be very useful for me to create, somehow, subsets of tables around the concept of a "user/tenant". Of course, this is something that could be managed by my application logic, however, my users would require a more clear/secure data isolation.

Anyway, as said, very new to DynamoDB and most probably I'm missing a lot of things.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, there is no specific "database", all the tables are just under your aws account. Using some form of naming convention might be the best option if you need some kind of namespacing.