# AWS DynamoDB creating a database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When I go to AWS console it asks me to create a DynamoDB table `Create DynamoDB table`. But I don't have a DynamoDB database yet. How come I create a DynamoDB table without a database?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDb is not like other databases.  You just create tables.  Essentially, the DynamoDb access for your account *is* the database, so you are ready to start adding tables.  You can't do joins between tables. Check out [How to create a database in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654666/how-to-create-a-database-in-dynamodb) which asks and answers a very similar question.

I think this article also lists helpful things you should know: https://cloudacademy.com/blog/amazon-dynamodb-ten-things/

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Does DynamoDb table get a limitation? Say max amount of data in a table?

Comment: No, it is essentially infinitely scalable in terms of the number of items (akin to rows), but there are limits on the item size.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html for all limits that apply.